# Affliate tracking cookie/code works through an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies, session-cookies, affiliate

So if one is given an affiliate link, for example www.clickbank.hop.userid.com and he places his link inside an iframe, on a website: does he still get the proper commissions from a buyer visiting said website?

Let's assume that clickbank has no iframe breaker code. Also I'm not sure which one but I think clickbank uses a tracking cookie or code.

I appreciate any answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no breaker code, any affiliate link should work if it is loaded in an iframe. However there are some major drawbacks

- Users that disable 3rd party cookies will not be tracked and you will not get commission (note that Safari does this by default). This is because any cookies stored in an iframe count as 3rd party.
- It is possible that the affiliate could check if an iframe is being used and decide not to get commission however I see no reason for this to happen, it maybe worth checking however